# Google Vision AutoML > Datasets | Validation data in csv doesn't upload

Tags: google-vision, google-cloud-automl

I am using Google Vision Automl. In order to train a model the data needs to be uploaded. There are following two ways.

1. Upload directly from your computer
2. Upload to google bucket and make a csv which contains the paths to the image files.

See the following image

[image]

Since, i want to compare my locally pre-trained model with the model i will train on Google Automl, i want to ensure that the same data splits are used (train, test, validation). So #2 way is the best way

**Issue:**
I have made a the csv in the following format. But when i upload it, only train and test sets are loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting "**Validation**" instead of "**Validate**" in the set column.

So the issue was the language used on the upload form, where they have the following.

> Optionally, you can specify the TRAIN, **VALIDATE**, or TEST split.

Which is misleading and they also did not show the sample row for Validation.

For more details:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare#csv